# Add another value to a dictionnary key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

in python i try to add another values for an existing dict.
There is my existing dict :

```
d = {'132': '5ff446ee8', '133': '5ff446ef8871e234'}
```

I want add for each key a value, to get this :

```
d = {'132': ['5ff446ee8',"new_value"], '133': ['5ff446ef8871e234',"new_value2"]}
```

Sorry for my bad english, i have no idea how to do this !
If you can help my, i will be greatful

Comment: If you expect more values to be added to the dictionary, I'd suggest making the values a list from the start (with 1 element initially). This way you can always treat the values as lists and don't need to handle separate cases for `'5ff446ee8'` vs `['5ff446ee8',"new_value"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dict Comprehensions` and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and for creating a list use `f-string` for `new_value`.

```
>>> {k: [v, f'new_value_{idx}'] for idx, (k,v) in enumerate(d.items(), start=1)}

# If you want exactly your desired output try like below
>>> {k: [v, f'new_value{"" if idx==1 else idx}'] for idx, (k,v) in enumerate(d.items(), start=1)}
```

---

```
{'132': ['5ff446ee8', 'new_value1'], '133': ['5ff446ef8871e234', 'new_value2']}


{'132': ['5ff446ee8', 'new_value'], '133': ['5ff446ef8871e234', 'new_value2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you.

```py
d = {'132': '5ff446ee8', '133': '5ff446ef8871e234'}

d["132"] = [d["132"], "new_value"]

print(d)
#output : {'132': ['5ff446ee8', 'new_value'], '133': '5ff446ef8871e234'}
```

You can perform this operation in a for loop on all keys of the dict

like :

```py
d = {'132': '5ff446ee8', '133': '5ff446ef8871e234'}

new_dict = {}

for key, value in d.items():
    new_dict[key]=[value, "new_value"]

print(new_dict)

#output : {'132': ['5ff446ee8', 'new_value'], '133': ['5ff446ef8871e234', 'new_value']}
```

Sorry for my bad english =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep simple you can declare you dictionary values as an empty list and just append the new values.

```
d = {'132': [], '133': []}
d['132'].append('5ff446ee8')
d['133'].append('5ff446ef8871e234')
d['132'].append('new_value')
d['133'].append('new_value2')

print(d)
{'132': ['5ff446ee8', 'new_value'], '133': ['5ff446ef8871e234', 'new_value2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want more values to be added to existing keys in an existing dictionary, you could from the start make all the values as lists this way it'll be easier to add values whenever you wish, however here's my approach to achieve what you asked for:

```
def add_value(data, key, value):
    if key in data.keys():
        if type(data[key]) is list:
            data[key] = data[key] + [value]
        else:
            data[key] = [data[key]] + [value]
    else:
        data[key] = value

    return data
```

Here's an example:

```
d = {'132': '5ff446ee8', '133': '5ff446ef8871e234'}
add_value(d, '132', 'new_value')
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'132': ['5ff446ee8', 'new_value'], '133': '5ff446ef8871e234'}
```

You could even implement this as a new class:

```
class NewDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)

    def add_value(self, key, value):
        if key in self.keys():
            if type(self[key]) is list:
                self[key] = self[key] + [value]
            else:
                self[key] = [self[key]] + [value]
        else:
            self[key] = value
```

You could use it as follows:

```
d = {'132': '5ff446ee8', '133': '5ff446ef8871e234'}
new_d = NewDict()
new_d.update(d)
new_d.add_value('132', 'new_value')
print(new_d)
```

Output:

```
{'132': '5ff446ee8', '133': '5ff446ef8871e234', '123': 'new_value'}
```